# undefined length array in class constructor

Tags: c++

I've been trying to use arrays in a class constructor. Here is my code:

```
struct Motor_Group{
    int Motors[3];
    int Encoder;
}; 
int main()
{
    Motor_Group Left_Drive {{2,3},3};
    Motor_Group Right_Drive {{2,3},3};
    cout<< sizeof(Left_Drive.Motors)/sizeof(int);
    return 0;
}
```

But, the problem is that i want to make the length of the array `motors` to be undefined untill its contents is declared. How can i do that?

Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: There's nothing special about a constructor, when it comes to declaring local arrays. You declare and use arrays in a constructor in a 100% identical fashion as you would declare and use arrays in any other function or class method. Whatever you're currently doing when it comes to using arrays in some other function, you simply do exactly the same thing here. It's unclear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: try std::vector?

Comment: Array sizes must be known at compile-time

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need MotorGroups to be of the same type, 
then you could template the array size.

Using [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t motor_count>
struct Motor_Group{
    std::array<int,motor_count> Motors;
    int Encoder;
}; 
int main()
{
    Motor_Group<2> Left_Drive {{2,3},3};
    Motor_Group<3> Right_Drive {{2,3,4},3};
    std::cout<< Left_Drive.size();
    // Left_Drive = Right_Drive; // Error at compile time, since Motor_Group<2> != Motor_Group<3>
    return 0;
}
```